# Is there a way to convert a string to a proper array, not an array of strings or an array of characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I have this string **“[{value: 1400, value1: 50, value2: 48}, {value: 1500, value1: 20, value2: 88}]"** and I need to convert into a list **[{value: 1400, value1: 50, value2: 48}, {value: 1500, value1: 20, value2: 88}]** in JavaScript, is there a way to do that??

Comment: JSON.parse would do that for you

Comment: @Singh3y Nope, the given string is not JSON.

Comment: i tried using JSON.parse. that did not work

Comment: Yeah @Teemu you are correct. Maybe you can try appending 2 characters in starting like "a:${yourString}" then parse it. I don't think it should cause any issue then and you can access it using ````parsed = JSON.parse(`a:${yourString}`);console.log(parsed.a)````

Comment: @Singh3y, thanks a lot, let me try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `eval()` function. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Please be aware, that `eval()` shouldnt be used generally as you can read in the article above.

Example:

```
const array = eval('[{value: 1400, value1: 50, value2: 48}, {value: 1500, value1: 20, value2: 88}]');
```

Edit:
I would suggest to modify you string to fit the JSON-Standard.
To achieve this, you would have to put the keys of your objects in quotation marks like this:

```
let yourString =  '[{"value": 1400, "value1": 50, "value2": 48}, {"value": 1500, "value1": 20, "value2": 88}]';
const array = JSON.parse(`${yourString}`);
```

This will work ^^